# Problemas con el posicionamiento de iconos

Tags: css

Quiero centrar los iconos verticalmente dentro del `div` padre, pero no soy capaz. Mi código:

```css
.subtaskList {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-top: 17px;
}

#subtaskCheck {
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  border-radius: 3.84px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.subtaskTitle {
  vertical-align: 20%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

.alertSubtask {
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  color: #50E3C2;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  margin-left: -22px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="subtaskList">
  <i class="si si-bell alertSubtask" style="display: none;"></i>
  <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" data- subtaskid="255">
  <div class="subtaskTitle">qwerqwer qwerqwer xcvzxvxczv asdfasdf asdfñlasdf adsfasdfads asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfadsf adsfasdfasd asdfadsf adsfasdfadsf adsfasdfads fadsfdasf asdfasd fdasf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfadsf asd asdfasdf as</div>
  <input type="text" class="changeSubtaskName">
  <i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i>
</div>
```

Hay que tener el cuenta que el contenido del `div` subtaskTitle es aleatorio y siempre debe quedar centrado.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas he modificado algunas cosas, está claro que si el tamaño de la pantalla es muy pequeño no podremos mantener los elementos como dices y tendremos que usar [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/) para adaptar-los.

No obstante, tu código quedaria así:

```css
    .subtaskList {
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.07);
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
        padding-bottom: 17px;
        padding-top: 17px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #subtaskCheck {
        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;
        border-radius: 3.84px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .subtaskTitle {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family: Poppins-Regular;
        font-size: 12px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 60%;
        position: relative;
        top: 10px;
    }
    
    .alertSubtask {
        height: 23px;
        width: 23px;
        color: #50E3C2;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 23px;
        margin-left: -22px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="subtaskList">
    <i class="si si-bell alertSubtask" style="display: none;"></i>
    <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" data- subtaskid="255">
    <div class="subtaskTitle">qwerqwer qwerqwer xcvzxvxczv asdfasdf asdfñlasdf adsfasdfads asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfadsf adsfasdfasd asdfadsf adsfasdfadsf adsfasdfads fadsfdasf asdfasd fdasf asdfasdf asdf asdfa sdfadsf asd asdfasdf as</div>
    <input type="text" class="changeSubtaskName">
    <i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las propiedades de Flexbox para lograr esta técnica: aquí omití todos los estilos de los hijos, solo le puse este CSS al padre(.subtaskList):

CSS:

```
.subtaskList{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100px;
}
```